Hamachi Minecraft: Connection lost Timed out. Ubuntu Server LTS 20.04
Recently, I have been developing a Ubuntu Server on my laptop. I've installed forge on it, no mods downloaded yet and my friend (from Windows 11) can't connect to the server using Hamachi. This is not a big problem since my other friend can connect. Only one person can't connect to my server. He can ping the server, the error occures when he gets to the joining world section.
If anyone could help out that would be great.
